# call opcode gas consumption on a non EOA address depends if the addres is "new" or not

Tags: contract-development, gas, contract-invocation, eth-call

I have the following contract, reduced to the minimum for testing reasons:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.11;

contract PackedMultiplexer {
    function multiTransfer(address  _address1, uint _amount1, address  _address2, uint _amount2) payable public
    {
        assembly {
            pop(call(2300, _address2, _amount2, 0, 0, 0, 0))
            pop(call(2300, _address1, _amount1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I generate 2 new private keys.

I get 2 new public addresses `0x0c73c24c841ddDF2d476E7E2C1552Ea04364cc9A` and `0xC16F1C0241B1204BC123650CfCb3A03046F2d91C`, previously unknown to the network. Then I call the contract with those addresses and some random (constant) value for the amounts.

I get a [first TX](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6015cdbd489a4d1a07b28e04f9f28586dd171f30ec333d9120c2fe3c83f2f275) which consumes `87,191` gas.

I call a second time the contract with exactly the same parameters and get a [second TX](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xcddd326da77d8b83924b07403f7e6ba1ea0eab0cc19a09b0ac2f5469341fbf4d) which consumes `37,191` gas.

**My question:** why is the gas consumption of the first execution of the contract and the second execution is different? It seems to me in both cases the same code is executed? What am I missing?

As you can see in the debugger, the [first TX call opcodes](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x6015cdbd489a4d1a07b28e04f9f28586dd171f30ec333d9120c2fe3c83f2f275) consumes `37000` gas each; [the second TX call opcodes](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xcddd326da77d8b83924b07403f7e6ba1ea0eab0cc19a09b0ac2f5469341fbf4d) consumes `12000` gas each. Why is that? How can I prevent the `37000` gas consumption?

(**Note:** the question holds true if you replace `2300` (first argument of `call`) in the code by `gas()` or `0`.)

Comment: Because in the first transaction you change a state (account balance) from zero to non-zero, and in the second transaction you change it from non-zero to non-zero, which is 50% cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This does not seem to hold. I just tried.
I filled 150 addresses with some ethers: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5489e9916745c6f5a56083f8eff2596415599869c348d31c12f365e8d10a3e25
Then emptied them one by one (150 txs)
Then called the contract again: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc866d85457f018674ffcd29793e84506a2fd881aa484c3b0ffe2af7f3e0e0f1e
which consumed around 8300 gas / address, which is the lowest I can get (for new addresses it's around 25000 gas / address after the initial overhead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering the same thing, I ended up reading the yellow paper.

Turns out in p.35 they add `G_{newaccount}` to the gas cost, which is `G_{newaccount}: Paid for a CALL or SELFDESTRUCT operation which creates an account (25000).`

I couldn't find anywhere the definition of 'creating an account' which is odd (e.g. just tested: sending only an ERC-20 token to an address still force me to pay the 25k extra gas, so this is not considered as 'creating an account'...)

Comment: Erc20 transfer does not do anything directly to the account, only modifies a ledger, so that would explain why that doesn't count